# symofony4 custom route loader does't register

Tags: symfony4

src/Resources/config/routing.yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    App\Routing\ResourceRouteLoader:
        arguments:
            - '@App\Metadata\Resource\Factory\ResourceMetadataFactory'
            - 'App\Action\PlaceholderAction'
            - '%simple_rest.resource_class_directories%'
        tags: [ 'routing.loader' ]
```

config/routes/app_rest.yaml

```
app_rest:
    resource: .
    type: app_rest
    prefix: /api
```

the ResourceRouteLoader service is in the service container, but has no 'routing.loader' tag

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Conclusion

It seems the `imports` from config/services.yaml doen't work as expected , it works when I move all my services from directory `src/Resources/config/` to config/services.yaml file

Comment: Unused services are removed from the container, did you try to [use it](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html#using-the-custom-loader)?

Comment: @emix, I added 'routing.loader' tag to that service, Symfony4 is supposed to add it to its route  resolver service.

Comment: No, you did 50% of the work. Did you read the documentation? I posted the link above.

Comment: I see, I updated  question, I forgot to put the code that use the custom route loader.

Comment: the problem is solved ,when move ResourceRouteLoader service from src/Resources/config/routing.yaml to config/services.yaml, this is strange

Comment: Services are not loaded from the routing configuration file.